# OpenTelemetry in an multi-tenant ASP.NET Core app

Tags: c#, azure, open-telemetry, azure-monitor

We are developing a multi-tenant application with a common Web API for all the tenants and tenant specific databases.

We are planning to use a single azure application insights using OpenTelemetery for instrumentation.

Questions

- How can we ensure that the tenant of is populated in all the metrics, logs and traces. We are determining the tenant Id in a custom middleware during the runtime.

Thanks -nen

Comment: Which SDK are you using? Can you paste here a name of a nuget package?

Comment: "Azure.Monitor.OpenTelemetry.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.0" 
"OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting" Version="1.7.0" 
"OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore" Version="1.7.1" 
"OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Http" Version="1.7.1" 
"OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Runtime" Version="1.7.0"